# Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions with React-Native

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I have a React-Native application I am attempting to integrate with a SDK from MaaS360 a MDM platform.

Everything works until built and attempting to init the views.

```
2017-02-10 14:52:06.844697 AppName[1675:604526] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UIViewController: 0x10122ae20>.
2017-02-10 14:52:08.721767 AppName[1675:604526] *** Assertion failure in +[FLCRKeyServicesUtils getDeviceBasedKeyUsingMKSharedRounds], /u002/AppSDK/3.02.000.SDK_93/core/core/FLCRKeyServicesUtils.m:472
2017-02-10 14:52:08.723552 AppName[1675:604526] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'MK shared rounds is not loaded yet'
```

Above in the error:  Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for

I think this has to do with my rootView and initMaaS360SDK both living in the application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions bool, but I don't know where to go from here.

The SDK is meant to run at application launch and ensure the device is allowed to run the internal application, however the SDK fails to fully run as it's initialize happening on top of react-native's own rootView I think.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

{

  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"AppName"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  //sdk integration
  [self initMaaS360SDK];
  return YES;


}
```

If it matters I am using React-Native 0.37.0, and iOS Target 8.0.

Comment: please accept my answer if it solves your problem! It helps me and others on this community to grow and help each other!

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same issue in the past. This has to do with MaaS360. The cause of this error is that you forgot to add `com.fiberlink.authServices` to your Keychain Sharing capability.

Good luck!

Bas du Pre